# How to use YEAR(date) in mysql query with zend framework2

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework2

```
$sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
$select = $sql->select()
->from('user')
->columns(array('Email'=> 'email'))
->where(array(  new Expression('YEAR(date)') => '2014'));
```

It shows Warning: Illegal offset type in ...

I want to write below query:

```
SELECT `user`.`email`
FROM `user`
WHERE YEAR(user.date) = 2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
->where(array(  new Expression('YEAR(date)') => '2014'));
```

What about using this instead:

```
->where('YEAR(date) = ?', '2014');
```

Or perhaps this:

```
->where('YEAR(user.date) = ?', '2014');
```

You can find more examples in [the official Zend documentation on `Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html).